# Can this LINQ Expression be converted from method syntax to query syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to convert this LINQ method expression to an equivalent query syntax:

```
var results1 =
    logins.GroupBy(loginDate => loginDate.Date)
        .Select(loginDates => new
            {
                Date = loginDates.Key,
                Count = loginDates.Select(login => login.Name).Distinct().Count()
            });
```

First, I came to this syntax, which does provide the same result, but isn't really the same.

```
var results2 =
    from loginDate in logins
    group loginDate by loginDate.Date
    into loginDates
    select new
        {
            Date = loginDates.Key,
            Count = (from login in loginDates group login by login.Name).Count()
        };
```

The difference is that I'm using a `group by` statement here, which isn't the same as distinct (although it does provide the same result). Then I tried this:

```
var results3 =
    from loginDate in logins
    group loginDate by loginDate.Date
    into loginDates
    select new
        {
            Date = loginDates.Key,
            Count = (from login in loginDates select login.Name).Distinct().Count()
        };
```

However, this code is using quite some method syntax again.

It my last example the best you can get? Or is it possible to rewrite the query using less method syntax and more query syntax?

---

The `logins` is initialized like this:

```
var logins = new[]
                 {
                     new {Name = "james", Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01)},
                     new {Name = "jamie", Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01)},
                     new {Name = "alex", Date = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01)},
                     new {Name = "james", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)},
                     new {Name = "matt", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2)},
                     new {Name = "jamie", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2)},
                     new {Name = "alex", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2)},
                     new {Name = "james", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2)},
                     new {Name = "james", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 2)}
                 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a query form for `Distinct` (see this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2006/11/19/linq-farm-group-and-distinct.aspx) for why). The query syntax with `group by` is semantically equivalent, and is what I would go with if you want it in query form.

Comment: I don't know if I'd consider group by semantically equivalent, but you get the Answered checkmark because of the link to *why* there is no query form for Distinct.

Comment: @comecme: My statement is that your query with `group by` is semantically equivalent to your query with `Distinct`. Also, note that `GroupBy(g => g).Select(g => g.Key)` is effectively `Distinct`. This is why you can get a semantically equivalent query to your query using `Distinct` by using `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

afaik, LINQ query syntax has no `Distinct()` equivalent. Neither `Count()`, `Sum()`, etc. So you have to combine method/query syntax or use just method.